# Can't Get Computer directory

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This is an unusual problem that I have never faced before.

For some unknown reason when I opened Explorer there was no way for me to see the `Computer` drive directory.  Also when I tried to Save a photo (For example) the popup box did not show the drives.

I tried another File Manager and had no problem. Why isn't explorer working?

Comment: Not sure about root cause, but I'd first try to restart explorer.exe.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me today. When I plugged in a drive, the Autoplay menu would not come up and My Computer didn't show any devices, so I was not able to access any local files.

Restarting the computer fixed it, so it was most likely a bug in explorer.exe. Try killing that process in Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>) and then restarting it
(File → Create New Task (Run...) → "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe").

Comment: Tried but no success.  Also rebooted.

Comment: Do you have any other computers with the same OS? If you do, try copying `explorer.exe` from it to the non-working computer and see if it runs

Comment: I have one with a Vista OS. I could try that one. I'll let you know it it works.